# XSD Schema Validation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, xsd

I have found several sources regarding how to validate an xml document against a schema, but I have an application in ruby in which I need to validate that a user supplied schema is a valid schema itself.  Is there a way to that I can check this?  Is there an XSD schema to validate an XSD schema?  Or are there libraries or gems that do this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As schemas are XML documents themselves you can validate them like any other document. Both an XSD and a DTD for XML Schema can be found on this site http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) for this:

```
begin
  schema = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read('invalid_schema.xsd'))
rescue Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError => e
  puts "Invalid XML Schema!"
end
```

Comment: I strongly recommend nokogiri for this, especially over libxml from practical experiance.

Comment: If you need XSD 1.1 validation, then you're out of luck: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1024